# Что лучше: тире или двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Мне кажется, что в этом предложении лучше поставить двоеточие.

"Компания обновила и переоборудовала Отдел технического контроля - на текущий момент осуществляет полный цикл контроля поступающей на склад и производимой продукции, включающий ВИК, испытания и анализ химического сырья и готовой продукции".

Answer (score 1):

1."...Обновила и переоборудовала" - это как? Переоборудовала - это и есть обновила. Если не только переоборудовала, то что еще сделала? Обновила/расширила штат, реструктурировала, расширила функции? Что нового, кроме оборудования? В документах надо формулировать точно, а не на уровне "компания сделала отделу хорошо".

2."...Контроля поступающей на склад и производимой продукции". Очень странная последовательность: сначала отправляем на склад, а потом производим.

3."...осуществляет полный цикл контроля" - махровая канцелярщина. Даже в канцелярском тексте можно сказать проще: осуществляет полный контроль, от... до...

Итог:

Компания переоборудовала отдел технического контроля. Теперь он осуществляет полный контроль производимой и поступающей на склад продукции, от ВИК до испытаний и анализа химического сырья и готовой продукции.

Answer (score 0):

Кто "осуществляет"? Он? Надо вставить.
Отдел с прописной вряд ли уместен.
"На текущий момент" – очень плохо. В настоящее время? Или по-простому – сейчас.
Что такое "поступающей на склад и производимой"?
В общем, корявая фраза, надо изменить.

Я бы вместо вашего тире поставил просто точку.

Comment: Ну насчет "поступающей и производимой" у меня вопросов не возникает, вроде все понятно. Вариант с точкой тоже хорош. Но если выбирать между двоеточием и тире, то что нужно выбрать? У Розенталя прочитала, что если вторая часть заключает в себе следствие или вывод из того, о чем говорится в первой части, и можно подставить "поэтому", то ставится тире. Здесь "поэтому" вроде можно подставить. Вывод - тире на месте?

Comment: Нет, здесь "поэтому" поставить нельзя. Какое же это следствие?
И "а именно" поставить нельзя, поэтому двоеточие отметается.

Поэтому я и предлагаю ставить точку.

Если же надо выбирать из тире и двоеточия под дулом пистолета – выберу тире.

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, здесь нельзя поставить "поэтому", тем более "а именно". Можно поставить точку, ну или точку с запятой. Тире и двоеточие исказили бы смысл предложения.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, компания получает химическое сырье и производит из него продукцию, при этом требуется контроль как сырья, так и продукции. Возможно, полный цикл  контроля – это термин, обозначающий проведение контроля после каждой технологической операции. Также следует уточнить,  кто ( в данном сообщении)  контролирует – компания или отдел. Соответственно, можно предложить два варианта оформления предложения:

(1) "Компания обновила и переоборудовала отдел технического контроля и  на текущий момент осуществляет полный цикл контроля поступающей на склад и производимой продукции, включающий ВИК, а также испытания и анализ химического сырья и готовой продукции".

(2) "Компания обновила и переоборудовала отдел технического контроля, который  на текущий момент осуществляет полный цикл контроля поступающей на склад и производимой продукции, включающий ВИК, а также испытания и анализ химического сырья и готовой продукции".

Answer (score 0):

Переоборудовала отдел - так не говорят.
Переоборудовать можно помещение отдела.